# changing boolean values in php

Tags: php, variables, boolean

I  have a bunch of values from checkboxes that are boolean. Al I want to do is set them to yes if they are 1 and no if they are 0.

My code fails, looks ok to me?

```
$item =  $form_state['values']['item1'] == 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your checkboxes have *value attribute* equal to 1, it should be OK:

```
<input ... type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

If you have not set these values or in all the cases you may just check, if they exists in `$_GET` or `$_POST` array (assuming `$form_state` is taken from there):

```
$item = isset($form_state['values']['item1']) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

The above example, should works for you. Keep in mind radio buttons and check boxes will not be set in `$_GET` or `$_POST` if they are not selected, at all, which also may generate *Notice* or *Warning*, if trying to access non-existing index.

In older versions of php you might need to use `$_REQUEST`.